# Python: Find substring that has inner whitespace

Tags: python

I have a list of words. I am checking if any of these words occur inside a file. This is my code:

```
for word in wordlist:
    print word
    for thefile in filelist:
        handle = open(thefile)
        filecontents = handle.read()
        if word in filecontents:
            print word, 'occurs', "in", thefile
        handle.close()
```

The code works perfectly if all the words on my list are single words. It does not work if any of the words is a phrase (i.e. two words with an inner whitespace. For example, "message broker").

Where am I going wrong? I am new to Python.

[update]
Here is my list of words:

- install
- postreq
- message broker

The code reports all instances of files that have 'install' in them, and 'postreq', but does not report anything at all for 'message broker'. I know there are files that have this phrase ('message broker').

Comment: There is no reason `'some words' in 'this sentence has some words in it'` would return `False`.

Comment: why are you repeatedly opening and closing the file? Are you sure you don't have `"message broker\n"` and the case is the same?

Comment: How did you realized that " It does not work if any of the words is a phrase"?

Comment: As pointed out in above comment "message broker" should be in "Some message broker statement" unless you have "Some message \n broker statement"

Comment: Can you give an example of a phrase that does not work? How about a sample file? This will make debugging much easier.

Comment: By the way, strings can include whitespace, so you can do `print word, 'occurs in', thefile`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham @ShantanuDeshpande Yes, I am sure I don't have `message broker\n` or `message \n broker`

Comment: @user5000735, well your code is then defying all logic, add your list of words and what the phrases are failing on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake **has** to be in how you create `wordlist`-- which you don't show. Perhaps you create it with `<string>.split()`, which splits at every whitespace. Or perhaps you're reading your word list from a file with `readlines()`, which doesn't throw away the final newline. Without a doubt, if `"message broker"` is in your list of words, it *will* match any string containing the same sequence of characters (with just one *space* between the words).

In fact, if you construct your list correctly your code will *over* respond: It will tell you that *"bat"* occurs in *"manufacturer's re**bat**e"*, for example. Which it does, because it's a substring.

Comment: Yes, I am using `word = word.strip()` That isn't the correct way?

Comment: How about you show how you construct your word list, and someone will fix it pronto.

Comment: Sorry, I read `split()`, not `strip()`! My bad. Using `strip()` is a good idea, and shouldn't drop _internal_ spaces.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect. I just used `rstrip()` and found 5 occurrences of 'message broker' in the directory.
I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, but yes, that's where I was going wrong.

Comment: Glad you got better results now, though I'm not quite sure why :-). Do show how you make your list.

Comment: PS. If you consider your problem solved, "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark. You're allowed that already.

Comment: Like this:   `fwordlist = open(fname)  
for word in fwordlist:  
    word = word.rstrip()  
    wordlist.append(word)`

Comment: Hmm, it looks like `strip()` (not `split()`) ought to have worked, actually. Try this and post the results: `print wordlist`.

Comment: If I use `print repr(wordlist)`, I get `['install', 'postreq', 'message broker']`

Comment: That must be what you get after `rstrip()`; because it won't do anything to this lot. But never mind, your code works now, right?